# JSON_ARRAY_APPEND para arrays bidimencionales

Tags: mysql, json

Tengo una consulta, tengo un procedimiento almacenado que le llega un parámetro `prod` de tipo json y ejecuta lo siguiente:

```
UPDATE tabla SET productos = JSON_ARRAY_APPEND(productos, '$', prod) WHERE cod = 1;
```

La tabla es así:

```
cod  productos
----------------
1    [[1,2],[3,4]]
```

y si supongamos que el prod es `'[[5,6],[7,8],[9,10]]'` lo que espero que pase es que quede es:

```
'[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8],[9,10]]'
```

Pero me queda así

```
'[[1,2],[3,4],[[5,6],[7,8],[9,10]]]'
```

¿Cómo podría solucionarlo? Además el prod es dinámico, puede tener 3 elementos, o 1, o 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes usar [`JSON_MERGE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-merge)

#### Ejemplo:

```sql
UPDATE tabla SET productos = JSON_MERGE(productos, prod) WHERE cod = 1;

# [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8], [9, 10]]
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7tvrGVM52gzhrQE96KgdcE/0)</kbd>

Comment: Muchas gracias! En mi caso sería `UPDATE tabla SET productos = JSON_MERGE(productos, prod) WHERE cod = 1;`

Answer (score 0):

En vez de *append* usa *merge*.
Con `json_array_append()` estas agregando un arreglo de arreglos que queda como tercer elemento; como es una operación entre arreglos mejor usa `json_merge_preserve()`:

```
SELECT json_merge_preserve( productos, prod )
  FROM ( SELECT json_array( json_array(1,2)
                          , json_array(3,4)
                          ) productos
              , json_array( json_array(5,6)
                          , json_array(7,8)
                          , json_array(9,10)
                          ) prod
       ) t
```

Resultado:

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8], [9, 10]]
```